# Missing Semicolon in JSON file, VSCode not identifying problem line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I'm trying to import this small JSON file into another webpage

```
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 72053645,
        "name": "Weather Report",
        "type": "Flip Effect Monster",
        "desc": "FLIP: Destroys all of your opponent's face-up \"Swords of Revealing Light\" on the field. If \"Swords of Revealing Light\" is destroyed, you can perform your Battle Phase twice this turn (or your next turn, if activated during your opponent's turn).",
        "atk": 950,
        "def": 1500,
        "level": 4,
        "race": "Aqua",
        "attribute": "WATER",
        "banlist_info": {
          "ban_tcg": "Banned",
          "ban_ocg": "Limited"
        },
        "card_images": [
          {
            "id": 72053645,
            "image_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/72053645.jpg",
            "image_url_small": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_small/72053645.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 81122844,
        "name": "Wind-Up Carrier Zenmaity",
        "type": "XYZ Monster",
        "desc": "2 Level 3 monsters\nOnce per turn: You can detach 1 Xyz Material from this card; Special Summon 1 \"Wind-Up\" monster from your hand or Deck. When a face-up \"Wind-Up\" monster on the field is destroyed and sent to your Graveyard (except during the Damage Step): You can detach 1 Xyz Material from this card to target that monster; return that target to the hand.",
        "atk": 1500,
        "def": 1500,
        "level": 3,
        "race": "Machine",
        "attribute": "WATER",
        "archetype": "Wind-Up",
        "banlist_info": {
          "ban_tcg": "Banned",
          "ban_ocg": "Limited"
        },
        "card_images": [
          {
            "id": 81122844,
            "image_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/81122844.jpg",
            "image_url_small": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_small/81122844.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

But whenever I try to run my code it keeps coming back with this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/services/testbanlist.js
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (2:10)

  1 | {
> 2 |     "data": [
    |           ^
  3 |       {
  4 |         "id": 72053645,
  5 |         "name": "Weather Report",
```

Does anyone else see where the error in my code is? VSCode is not showing exactly where a semicolon needs to go.

Comment: The error is you've named a JSON file .js, so the braces are starting a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) not an object.

Answer (score 1):

The extension of file should be .json.
testbanlist.json not testbanlist.js